# Remove icon from Win32 resources in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms

While making a Forms app, I added an icon file to the Icon field of the resources:

[image: Project properties screenshot]

I now changed my mind, and want to use the default icon. Is there a way to clear that field? I tried deleting the file, and now it just won't compile. Restarting Visual Studio does nothing.

I know there's a way to get the default icon from the assembly files, but isn't there a way to simply reset that to its original state?

Comment: Right click project then click Edit Project File in that file remove every line that has icon file name

Comment: It is going to take a while to fix the clumsiness and bugs in those property pages agilely.  Meanwhile, edit the project file and delete the `ApplicationIcon` element by hand.

Comment: ...and the `<ItemGroup>` that also references it. As Hans mentioned, this new interface is still in a work in progress. You could also specify a file that is not an icon at all and then you cannot remove it with the same tool used to add it. It will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry its too late, but in the space for the icon option should appear a settings icon, there you can put it to its default state

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As lydaf already said it can be done through the cogweel icon. I included some images to make it clearer

[Cogwheel icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lmQU.png)

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCk4B.png)